# Polygon edges and sides distorted in rayshader render

Tags: r, ggplot2, rayshader, geom-sf

I've been trying to plot a 3D plot of some spatial polygons, but I cannot render the sides and edges of the polygons properly. Below is the code I used to produce the plot below.

```
# Produce the 2D plot first.
ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = strips, aes(geometry = geometry, fill = total_fish, col = total_fish), col = "NA") +
      theme(legend.position = "left") + labs(fill = "Relative 
      fish biomass") +
      xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
      theme_bw() -> ppp
    ppp

# Render the 3D image.
plot_gg(ppp, multicore = T, width = 5, height = 5, scale = 350, raytrace = T, 
        windowsize = c(8000, 8000), zoom = 0.8, phi = 60, theta = 60)
Sys.sleep(0.2)
render_snapshot(clear = T)
```

[image]

**THINGS I'VE ALREADY TRIED:** Assigning a color to the edges, changing the thickness of the edges (by using the `linewidth` argument) playing with the `pointcontract` argument within the `plot_gg` function, changing the windowsize-scale-dimensions of the render.

Thanks for your help in advance, and please let me know if you need a fully reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `rayshader` and `ggplot 3.4.0` or later have some issues, using `linewidth` would not fix the problem. Hopefully, future updates of either or both packages will fix this. Meanwhile, you could switch back to `ggplot 3.3.6` to clean 3D images.

Restart Rstudio:

```
library(remotes)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.3.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Then, re-run your code should fix the problem. If not, please share a reproducible example. Others could test it on their machines.

Comment: Thank you. Downgrading to the older version of ggplot2 + using the offset_edges=T solved the issue nearly fully. There is still some bleeding, but it is tolerable.